# Why is this not responsive for small mobile?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for this coding. It works as intended for XL to medium-sized mobiles but does not centre when using smaller screen sizes. I played around with the col but couldn't figure out what the problem is. What could be the issue? I added a screenshot to clarify what I mean. As on the screenshot, the login box is not centred so that you have to scroll to the right to see the whole box. However, for all other sizes, it centres it.

[see here for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgOfF.jpg)

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <body class="bg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm offset-lg-4 offset-md-2">
              <div class="card" style="border-color: yellow; box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="height:10rem" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Login</h5>
                      <div class="card-text">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="email">Email</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="pass">Password</label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass">
                        </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="button">Login</button>
                          <p></p>
                          <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                          <p> Don't have an account? <a href="#">Sign up</a> </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The box is being cut off on the right-hand side and is not centred.

Comment: you did not describe how you expect the webpage to behave .... please update your question with a clear description .... `margin: 0 auto;` will center the login box ...  `<div class="card" style="border-color: yellow; box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); width: 18rem;align-items: center; margin: 0 auto;">`

Comment: I added a screenshot for clarification purposes.

Comment: i tested your code ... the login box is not resizable, so there will be some part of it missing

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you can't have `<div>` inside of a `<p>`